# call stack: catch vs. throws

Tags: java, exception

When to use "catch" and when to use "throws"?

```
try {
    //stuff
} 
catch (MyException me) {
    //stuff
}
```

versus

```
public void doSomething() throws MyException {
    //stuff
}
```

In the case of "throws", where to place my catch along the call stack?

```
Main
    ----- Function 1
        ----- Function 2
            ----- Function 3 (generate exception)
```

If I propagate the exception from function 3 to function 2, why shouldn't function 2 do the same? So at the end I would end up managing all the exceptions in the "main" and I think it's not a go0d practice to put all the code inside a try block, isn't it?

So what's the logical way to choose between "catch" and "throws"? And in the second case, where should I place my catch in the call stack?

Comment: You should only catch an exception if you know what to do with it.

Comment: My rules for catch: only catch when 1) there is some sensible action to be done; or 2) logging *and* re-throwing. Unfortunately, Java also makes me add; 3) to wrap a checked exception into an unchecked exception where propagation of said checked exception through `throws` is too cumbersome.

Comment: Use catch when you want to catch it and throws when you don't.  Of course, what you "want" to do depends to a large degree on your "contract" with your user.

Answer (score 2):

They're basically inverse of each other. `throws` means that a function is allowed to throw an exception; `catch` means that a block (the `try`) block expects that an exception might get thrown, and is prepared to handle it.

To take the ball metaphor, a pitcher `throws` an exception that the catcher expects. The catcher `catches` the ball and handles it somehow. (Well, maybe the metaphor is a bit off, since the catcher usually handles the ball by throwing it back to the pitcher. :) ) Here, the pitcher is a method, and the catcher is a `try-catch-[finally]` block.

Comment: If you wanted to extend the baseball metaphor, every time you wanted to throw the ball back to the pitcher you would get a fresh pitcher.

Comment: @JasonSperske Now we're getting philosophical! http://quotationsbook.com/quote/5712/#sthash.foUKSBpx.dpbs

Comment: Also you might want to add some explanation about checked vs. unchecked exceptions.  Checked exceptions are like pitches in a game of baseball, unchecked are like getting beaned in the head by a fly ball that was hit out of the park

Answer (score 0):

You should declare that a method throws a checked exception whenever it's necessary for the method's caller to catch it or pass it on. You should catch an exception whenever you are ready to handle that exception right then and there.

For example, if you're writing a program with a graphical interface that also has a core that reads from a file, the core classes are unequipped to tell the user there was an error, that's the graphical interface's job. So methods such as `getSomethingFromFile()` in a core program might throw `IOException`. If the graphical interface calls `getSomethingFromFile()` and determines there's a read error, the graphical interface can then display a dialog to the user, so it is ready then and there to catch the exception. In this case, the `getSomethingFromFile()` call should be enclosed in try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for a `throw - catch` approach to handle errors, then the actual error handling must be done by the component with the *responsibility* of doing so, in particular because this allows you to encapsulate the logic where it belongs.

The exception is catched by a certain class who knows what to do with it, and the course of action that must be taken. In some particular cases you can *rethrow* an exception by wrapping it in another one (setting the exception as its cause). Take any ORM as an example, any low level exception is wrapped in, for example, a `PersistenceException` that can have a SQLSyntaxException as its cause.

`throws` comes into play if you don't have the proper tools to manage the exception in a certain context and you want to propagate it to a higher layer/tier where it can be properly managed.

Let me put a "big picture example":

1. **Save** entity to database
2. Communication **error**
3. Exception is **thrown**, so your persistence object must **handle** it.
4. You **catch** it, wrap it and **rethrow** it as one of your own exceptions (I'm against letting persistence exceptions propagate to higher layers... but that's just me).
5. the persistence **throws** an exception that's **catched** by the model.
6. The model retries the operation.
7. Another failure (same **wrap + throw**).
8. The model notifies the failure and **elevates a report** to the view. This is what I meant by *being catched by the one who "knows" what to do*.
9. The view **displays** "No saving today, sorry" to the user.

The example contains both `throw` and `catch` cases, I hope it helps to clarify.

Comment: Your dislike for letting persistence exceptions propagate to higher layers isn't unique.  Unless an API documents every exception the caller should expect to handle, callers may be forced to use Pokemon exception handling.  The idea that routines' declarations should specify exceptions they expect to throw is actually a good one; the weakness in Java's implementation is the apparent assumption that if any caller will want to handle a condition, all callers will want to handle it.  Checked exceptions would be a good thing if...

Comment: ...one could specify concisely that method calls were not expected to throw any checked exceptions other than those explicitly caught, and any checked exceptions thrown thereby should be wrapped and rethrown as some other exception type.  Note that the fact that a method throws `SomeCheckedException` itself does not mean that a `SomeCheckedException` thrown in a nested call should be considered "expected" and propagate up.  If the code that calls the method isn't expecting the exception, it should get wrapped in an unchecked exception type.

Comment: @supercat You'd be surprised of some discussions I've had. Arguments like "A persistence exception is a persistence exception no matter the layer" simply seems absurd to me. My answer generally involves sarcasm "Oh, you're right! Just let me import Hibernate's exception hierarchy in my JSF Managed Bean"... I agree with you about that and about the use of unchecked exceptions. I always define my onw exception hierarchies and keep the checked ones as few as I can. My example was a simple one but checked vs unchecked is a whole topic itself.

Comment: The biggest failings in the exception-handling frameworks I'm familiar with (mainly Java and .net) are the presumptions that code that wants to *act on* an exception will expect to *resolve it*, and worse, that the *type* of an exception should generally suffice to answer both questions.  I would posit that in many cases, the proper pattern would be for code that gets an unexpected exception while working some data structures to expressly invalidate anything that might be corrupted.  If none of the things that might have been corrupted are ever needed, code goes back to running happily.

Comment: By contrast, if one of the things that that got corrupted is critically needed for the program to keep working, then the fact that it was invalidated will bring things to a crashing halt.  If code consistently followed the pattern that anything which might be corrupted by an unexpected exception would be expressly invalidated before the exception made its way up the call stack, then Pokemon exception handling would be safe.  Unfortunately, the pattern isn't widely followed and thus there's often no sensible way to handle unexpected exceptions.

Comment: @supercat A really interesting point of view, variety is what keeps code (and coding) greased. Unfortunately, when "something works" people tend to "leave it that way"... Nonetheless, exception handling could use a nice revamp in upcoming Java versions.